# Installing 3D Analyst extensions in ArcView 3.3 on 64bit Windows 10?

Tags: installation, 3d-analyst, 64bit, windows-10, arcview-3

I was using ArcView 3.2a version with 3D Analyst and spatial analyst extensions. Now i am not able to install 3D extension in my 64 bit computer windows 10.

How to install this extension?

Comment: Maybe ask ESRI...?

Comment: Are you using ArcView 3.2a, like your question body says, or ArcView 3.3, like your question title says?  Either way I would not expect installing 32bit software which was released nearly 15 years ago to work on the latest Windows 64bit operating system but I could be wrong: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/how-to-install-arcview3-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: You're asking about an extension to a software package that was released a dozen years ago, and hasn't been supported in nearly four.  At some point you just need to let it go. There are modern GIS packages which are fast and free, and which will work with modern operating systems.

Comment: Oracle VM with Windows7 can be a workaround. but consider using a newer GIS for support.